installing linux apps via terminal erro
every app that i am trying to install with apt-get is finally releasing the following error:
dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas' and package 'libglib2.0-0:i386'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
Then how can I really solve it .

Please edit the question and post the full error message

Also please provide OS & release (deb packages are built for specific releases; thus what you're running does matter)

Do you even understand the difference between apt-get and apt? This article explains. The main takeaway is - For day-to-day use, use apt.
